# API documentation in Enterprise Architect

Tags: api, enterprise-architect

This is my first time using EA. I used it to generate a class diagram from my C++ header files. Is there a way to add documentation to each method and/or variable and to generate a document that describes all the class' API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything in an EA model includes a Notes property. You can edit this by using the Notes window, among other ways (for instance, when working with a class's properties, the Attributes and Operations windows have an area for entering notes).

These notes will appear when you use the various tools on the Project->Documentation submenu.

Comment: Is there any actual API to build tools for EA?  I need to build a connector tool between Jira, Jama's Contour and EA.